# Set display or non-display condition to display feature in a GeoJSON file in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, features

I used the following code and put the displayed layers into a variable and selected the desired layer and I want features that have an area of less than 500m not to be displayed when the map zoom is changed.

```
map.on('moveend', function () {
    var existZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    if (existZoom <= 18) {
        let myLayers = map.getAllLayers();
        myLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
            if (layer.getProperties()['title'] == 'عوارض ساختمانی') {
                layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
                    if (feature.get('Area_arsa') <= 500) {

                        // Here is how to remove that feature //

                    };
                })
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Note: Because the size of my GeoJSON file is large, I want to lighten the map for display in different zooms to increase its loading speed.

Comment: And what is the question? What is not working in the above code?

Comment: In the part that I specified (...Here is how to remove that feature...), what code should I put that does not show the features that are included in the condition on the map

Comment: You should not need to remove any features, you can use a style function to display only as much detail as is appropriate for the resolution, for example https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-54w32e?file=/main.js when zoomed out only show major cities, when zoomed in show all cities.